# Is there a way to rotate an html table?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to rotate an html table? So, say I had a table like this:

> ```
>   <table id="table-1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
>         <tr><td>1</td></tr>
>         <tr><td>2</td></tr>
>         <tr><td>3</td></tr>
>         <tr><td>4</td></tr>
>         <tr><td>5</td></tr>
>         <tr><td>6</td></tr>
>     </table>
> ```

and wanted to some sort of button that had javascript behind it that could rotate the table any which direction. For example, clicking the right button, results in:

> ```
>   <table id="table-1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
>         <tr><td>6</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>3</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr>
>     </table>
> ```

I have a drag and drop plugin that uses a table, and I am trying to do a piece that allows for a user to add to a queue (that results in the table), and then they can also rotate it around as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
    var len = $('#table-1 tr').length;
    var $first = $('#table-1 tr').eq(0);
    for(var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        $('#table-1 tr').eq(1).find('td').prependTo($first);
        $('#table-1 tr').eq(1).remove();
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLknJ/

Answer (score 2):

There is [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) plugin.