# Table with different number of rows per column using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my controller, I have a data structure:

```
this.people = [
    {name: person1, spent: [1, 3, 5,...]},
    {name: person2, spent: [4, 57, 3,...]},
    ...
];
```

I would like to extract that data to a table-like structure in a way, that names are columns and elements of the spent table are rows of the corresponding column (where the column for each person can be of different length):

```
person1 | person2
1       | 4
3       | 57
5       | 3
```

Can I do it somehow with AngularJS and ng-repeat? Or in any other way that will not force me to explicitly loop through the elemens of the 'spent' for each person?

Comment: is the spent array lenght equal for each person ?

Comment: no, the arrays might have different lengths which I find the most problematic part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more standard solution, you need to know what is the highest length of spent array.

I propose :

```
$scope.maxSpent = function(){
    var max = [];
    for (var i in $scope.people){
        var p = $scope.people[i];
        if (p.spent.length > max.length){
            max = p.spent;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

This will be recomputed very often, you may be smarter depending on how you get your people array.

When this is done, you can construct the table you want :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="n in maxSpent()" ng-init="count = $index">
        <td ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.spent[count]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Nota-Bene, in the above solution, you can construct empty TD that will appear on the resulting table, it is up to you not to display them with :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="n in maxSpent()" ng-init="count = $index">
        <td ng-repeat="person in people" ng-if="person.spent[count]">{{person.spent[count]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct your array the normal way :

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="n in person.spent">{{n}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And in your css :

```
tr { display: block; float: left; }
th, td { display: block;}
```

With your list of people in the controller :

```
$scope.people = [
    {name: "person1", spent: [1, 3, 5]},
    {name: "person2", spent: [4, 57, 3,12]}
];
```

This is magic, and comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918094/html-table-with-vertical-rows)

Comment: And the content of <td>? If I put {{n}} there, then I get elements of person.spent in a row for each person, so can you indicate what content it should have to render what I wanted?

Comment: the CSS is the key to this answer

Comment: My apologies, wrong copy past. This should be better (Did not work with IE ...)

Comment: Ok, this solution works, but I have a feeling that it is a bit of a hack that doesn't allow me to go further with playing with the style of the table (e.g. applying bootstrap class table-striped results in a vertical stripe, not a horizontal; also, the columns do not fill up the whole table if I use bootstrap table class)... So I have still doubts about whether it is really the "correct" way to do it.

Comment: For sure this is a hack, but remember that TR = table row, then expect it to behave as a column is difficult.