# Vertical table with dynamic data

Tags: html, css, angular

**Seems to be the same requirement like [AngularJS "Vertical" ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308094/angularjs-vertical-ng-repeat) but solution doesn't work for *ngFor**

I have this `object array` that I am trying to bind to an HTML table. Its format is something like below:

```
[
 {
   "Animal":"Dog",
   "Country":"France",
   "Food":"Tofu",
   "Car":"Nano",
   "Language":"TypeScript"
 }
]
```

Now this can simply be formatted in the default HTML horizontal table way like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Animal</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Food</th>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th>Language</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of datas">
    <td>{{data.Animal}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Country}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Food}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Car}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Language}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This would create table like below(Please ignore the data in the table;its just to  give an idea.):

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG]

But how would I create a structure like this with dynamic data(kind of a vertical table):
[image]

Comment: Perhaps Google "angular vertical table" I see a lot of hits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS "Vertical" ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308094/angularjs-vertical-ng-repeat)

Comment: @Avitus Seemed exactly my requirement. But not working with Angular 2 `ngFor`. Throws errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Component:

```
this.arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(this.datas[0]);
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let key of arrayOfKeys">
        <th>{{key}}</th>
        <td *ngFor="let data of datas">
            {{data[key]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any specific reason behind using `ng-container`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-container` if You have data structure similar to `groups[].items[].name`

So, if You want to add row

```
<table>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups">
        <tr>
            <td>{{group.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of group.items">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086855/1840185

Comment: Consider my scenario, I have 2 lists coming from the service call, one list will be used as the table headings and another list will be used as the table data.
Something like this---

List 1 - {Name, Age}

List 2 - {Shubham, 25}

Table should look like - 

    Name    Shubham
    Age     25

Can anyone help?

Comment: So, You have a list that describes structure and another list that contains data. 
I would create a list `schema[].names[]` inside for loops above the example provided above.

Comment: Sure, please create minimal example that represents your problem I am willing to look into that.

Comment: Hi Viktor, Got it to work. Thanks a lot though :):):)