# Populate vertical table from two different arrays using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, arrays, json

I am trying to construct a vertical table from JSON data.However my problem is that I have 3 columns,First column is the name of that column.The remaining two columns have to be filled by 2 different arrays.

In this, 
[Vertical ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308094/angularjs-vertical-ng-repeat) question,using same array all columns are being populated,however i want to populate each column with different arrays
[image: Here the one column data is about one college and is coming from 1st array,second column should be filled by second array.]
This is my JSON

```
{
"result": {
    "college1": [
        {
            "lyr": "0",
            "rating": "",
            "code": "",
            "nirf": "0",
            "mhrd": "0",
            "outlook": "0",
            "tiem": "0",
            "career": "0",
            "naac": "0",
            "fees": "50000",
            "pla": "0",
            "image": "king.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "college2": [
        {
            "lyr": "0",
            "rating": "",
            "code": "",
            "nirf": "0",
            "mhrd": "0",
            "outlook": "0",
            "tiem": "0",
            "career": "0",
            "naac": "0",
            "fees": "25000",
            "pla": "0",
            "image": "king.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After working around,the solution i figured out is iterating over key,value pairs of my json array in ng-repeat. I used $index to iterate through second array.
This is my code:`

```
                <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in college1[0]">

                    <td class="col-md-6 head-field active">{{key}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="x in data1">
                        {{x[key]}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="x in data1">
                        {{college2[$index][key]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

`
Just posted the solution so that it might help someone facing similar problem in future :-)