# Printing out a table vertical instead of horizontal using PHP

Tags: php, html

Problem:

I have a table that prints out horizontal but I would like it to print vertical instead. Anyone who can give guidance on how this can be achieved?

PHP code

```
<?php
echo "<th>EKDA</th>";
echo "<th>C1</th>";
echo "<th>C2</th>";
echo "<th>C3</th>";
echo "<th>Nilai</th>";
echo "<th>Rank</th>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Vektor Eigen</th>";
for($tmbbb=0; $tmbbb<=2; $tmbbb+=1)
{
    echo "<td>$BPK2[$tmbbb]</td>";
}
echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<th>A1</th>";
{
for($tmb=0; $tmb<=1; $tmb+=1)
    echo "<th>$TAAAC1[$tmb]</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr><tr>";
echo "<th>A2</th>";

echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Curent output
[Curent output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHRZb.jpg)
Desired output:
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCpv8.jpg)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918094/html-table-with-vertical-rows

Comment: im use looping...

Comment: no need for loops. build your table normally "horizontal" . and use only 2 lines of CSS as in the question in the link.

Comment: consider the second high voted [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16919439/5407848) of the question

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code :

```
<?php
  echo "<th>EKDA</th>";
  echo "<th>C1</th>";
  echo "<th>C2</th>";
  echo "<th>C3</th>";
  echo "<th>Nilai</th>";
  echo "<th>Rank</th>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>Vektor Eigen</th>";
  for($tmbbb=0; $tmbbb<=2; $tmbbb+=1) {
    echo "<td>$BPK2[$tmbbb]</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";

  for($tmb=0; $tmb<=1; $tmb+=1) {
    if( $tmb==0 ) {
       echo "<tr><th>A1</th><th>$TAAAC1[$tmb]</th></tr>";
    }
    if( $tmb==1 ) {
      echo "<tr><th>A2</th><th>$TAAAC1[$tmb]</th></tr>";
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: its work but how i add 4 more data?
like this http://imgur.com/iHQnVn7
my code https://github.com/jazuly/ahp/blob/master/tes

Comment: Replace the `for` loop with this one- `for($tmb=0; $tmb<=1; $tmb+=1) {
    if( $tmb==0 ) {
       echo "<tr><th>A1</th><th>$TAAAC1[$tmb]</th><th>$TAAAC1[$tmb]</th><th>$TAAAC1[$tmb]</th></tr>";
    }
    if( $tmb==1 ) {
      echo "<tr><th>A2</th><th>$TAAAC1[$tmb]</th><th>$TAAAC1[$tmb]</th><th>$TAAAC1[$tmb]</th></tr>";
    }
  }`