# How to change a transposed table to make it horizontally scrollable?

Tags: html, css, html-table, horizontal-scrolling

I am making a table for products comparison. It's a table with vertical rows, a header at the left side and two or more product descriptions in vertical rows inside table body. It should be horizontally scrollable in case if user chooses a lot of products.

I have used CSS from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16919439/1429387) to transpose a table (i.e. make vertical rows). And now I can't manage to add a horizontal scrollbar inside `tbody` in case if table exceeds the predefined width. I am looking for something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17067294/1429387) but applied to my transposed table.

Here's what I have now: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naXa/cy21bLLp/1/) and here's what happens when I limit the table width to 200px:

[image]   [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the combination of `inline-block`s and `nowrap`:

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; white-space: nowrap; }
tr { display: block; float: left; }
th, td { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
tbody, thead { display: inline-block; }

tbody {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>number</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>James Bond</td>
      <td>007</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Lucipher</td>
      <td>666</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Jon Snow</td>
      <td>998</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

1. `table` shouldn't be displayed as block, if it not necessary for your other layout
2. I've added `white-space: nowrap` to prevent line wrapping
3. I've displayed `tbody` and `thead` as `inline-block` so now you can manage them like inline elements.

If you would like to scroll the `tbody` only without `thead`, it might looks like this:

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; white-space: nowrap; }
tr { display: inline-block; }
th, td { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }
tbody, thead { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }

tbody {
  width: 150px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
tbody tr { margin-right: -5px;}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>number</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>James Bond</td>
      <td>007</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Lucipher</td>
      <td>666</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Jon Snow</td>
      <td>998</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You can think about blocks layout instead. In fact you've already implemented itexcept the HTML what is a bad pattern.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried your solution. But blocks are still not arranged inline and there's no horizontal scroll - http://jsfiddle.net/naXa/cy21bLLp/3/

Comment: I see. You've decreased the width of `tbody` and would like to see a scoll bar for the `tbody` only. I've added an improvement to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be valid HTML, but you could wrap tbody with a div, then give the div the width and overflow-x property.