# HTML add data column by column instead of row by row

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 arrays in a external js file

```
var fruit = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var colour = ["yellow", "orange", "red", "orange"];
```

I need to store this data in a table.

```js
let p = document.getElementById('output1');
let fruit = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
p.innerHTML = fruit.map(i => `<td>${i}</td>`).join('');

p = document.getElementById('output2');
let colour = ["yellow", "orange", "red", "orange"];
p.innerHTML = colour.map(i => `<td>${i}</td>`).join('');
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>fruit</th>
    <th>colour</th>
  </tr>

  <tr id="output1"></tr>
  <tr id="output2"></tr>

</table>
```

This does not work as it is entered row by row. How can I make it enter column by column?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_headers

Comment: The question is `Javascript` based, not `CSS`

Comment: Okay, I was more sure that he was focusing on JS side.

Comment: Are these arrays always the same length?  Is there something wrong with using a `{ key: value }` object instead?

Comment: You should probably use `const` instead of `let` here.  The values never change and `let` or `var` often produce side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this. Here's a for loop: (note that I put an id of "foo" on the table)

```
for(var i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" +
            fruit[i] + "</td><td>" + colour[i] + "</td></tr>";
}
```

Avoid mutating innerHTML a bunch by appending to a temporary variable instead:

```
var tableHTML = "";
for(var i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
    tableHTML += "<tr><td>" + fruit[i] + "</td><td>" + colour[i] + "</td></tr>";
}
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML += tableHTML;
```

Take advantage of the second argument passed to the map callback:

```
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML += fruit.map((fruit, index) =>
        `<tr><td>${fruit}</td><td>${colour[index]}</td></tr>`).join("");
```

---

As a joke, you could transpose the table using CSS - stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16919439/1757964):

> If you want  to display columns, not rows, try this simple CSS
>
> ```
> tr { display: block; float: left; }
> th, td { display: block; }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two arrays into an array of strings using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map), then using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) insert those new strings into the `<tbody>` (which I added).

**Note:** This requires the arrays be the same length.

```js
let fruit = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
let colour = ["yellow", "orange", "red", "orange"];

let tblItems = fruit.map((item, index) => `<tr><td>${item}</td><td>${colour[index]}</td></tr>`)

document.querySelector('#fruit-colours > tbody').innerHTML = tblItems.join('')
```

```html
<table id="fruit-colours">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruit</th>
      <th>Colour</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```